# Sort datagridview by row header C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, sorting

I have a datagridview like this one:

```
         | foo | bar | baz | ...
------------------------------------------
Name 1   | asd | dsa | sad | ...
Name 2   | ...
Name 3   | ...
...      | ...
```

Name X is in RowHeaderCell and I want to sort this datagridview by name, how can I do that? datagridveiw.Sort() wors only for columns and not row headers...

thanks!

J.

Comment: Is this data-bound? And if so: what is the data source? a `DataTable`? a `List<T>`? A `BindingList<T>`? It matters...

Comment: yes it's data-bound, source is a dataTable, sorry, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this. You would need to respond to the row header clicked event and in that event handler implement the code you need to sort.